# Relation in orders multishipping Magento 2

Tags: magento2, multishipping

I need to work orders with multishipping, but Magento creates one order, each one with different ids, per added shipping.

Magento does have a method to relate all created orders when the order is multishipping? Or just it creates the orders separately and that is it.

The problem is, i'm trying to implement a payment method but as Magento creates several orders, i need to know what orders are from the same "parent" to then updated its status, comments etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can make relation between then via quote id.**

*For a Multishipping order's ,**`all order's  quote_id is same`**.*

If you  have *order object* then you can get *quote id* by `$orderObject->getQuoteId()`